# Message Popup with <a href>

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I am trying to create a pop up  when the application throws an exception .
The error is generated from  backend webservice

```
string urlNew = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Unable-to-log-into-Jira-Software-system-dashboard-v7-12-3/qaq-p/920444");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 string itSupprt = "IT Support request";
        sb.Append("Error: Id is already in use.").AppendLine();
        sb.Append("If assistance is required, please use ");
        sb.AppendFormat(@"<a href = '{0} {1}'   </a>", urlNew, itSupprt);
 throw new FaultException<ErrorMessage>(errorMessage, sb.ToString());
```

My expectation was to show  the pop up with a url , that can be clicked. 
But i got following as popup. The URl is not proper.

[image]

Any pointer whether it is achievable to have popup message with clickable url

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible using the default dialogue/alert box. If you want to put a URL, you can do it by using jquery's dialogue function. Here are some code examples: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

For that, you have to include Jquery-UI on your page.

Furthermore, you can also use a bootstrap dialogue box.